# Typescript: dynamically import classes

Tags: typescript, import

i like to dynamically import a Typescript Class.
I got everything running with the new dynamic function import but how do a dynamic class import?

i have a somehow dirty hack, which looks so:

```
// main.ts
async function main2() {
    const G = './test1'
    const TASK_IMPORT_FUNCTION = await import(G)
    const TASK_CLASS = TASK_IMPORT_FUNCTION.getTask()
    const TASK = new TASK_CLASS(__dirname)
    const R_TASK = TASK.run()
}
main2()

// test1.ts
export class Task {
    constructor(inputCwd: string) {}
    // ...
}

export function getTask() {
    return Task
}
```

So my question is: How can i get rid of the getTask() function and import the class directly in a dynamic way?

## Solution

```
// main.ts
async function main2() {
    const TASK_IMPORT = await import(G)
    const TASK_CLASS = TASK_IMPORT.Task
    const TASK = new TASK_CLASS(__dirname)
    const R_TASK = TASK.run()
}
main2()
```

Comment: What happens if you just write `const TASK_CLASS = TASK_IMPORT_FUNCTION.Task`?

Comment: this is running :-) i was blind then. thx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

do like me

```
const x = (async () => {
  
  let file = "./v";

  const f = await import( file);
  return f;
})().then(f => {
  
  const s = new f.default();
  s.run();
})
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
    console.error(error);
  });
```

here class

```
export  default class V{
  constructor() {

  }
  run(){
    console.log("fire");
  }
}
```

Comment: A like for the `new f.default()` string. It will get the class instance using in a JS default way.
But a dislike to the chaining notation with `async`/`await`. A success on `await` will step into the next statement if it is OK. Or will throw otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Task` class is in `task.ts`, you can use dynamic import:

```
const task = await import("./task");
```

when you need to import.