# typescript how to dynamically import?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic, import, require

I had some JS that would dynamically import and add a bunch of routes like this:

```
let routeFiles = [
  './routes/projects',
  './routes/scraper',
  './routes/admin',
  // etc
]

initRoutes(app) {
  for (let fn of routeFiles) {
    let routes = require(fn)
    app.use('/tix', routes)
  }
  debug.info('init routes done')
}
```

But with typescript I get an error

```
An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module.
```

Looking around there doesn't seem to be a clear answer

```
const mod = await require(fp)
```

this gives me an error of not being able to find the module as `.` even though I have checked the path being passed in:

```
(node:33353) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: Cannot find module "."
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/build/server.js:843:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/build/server.js:800:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/build/server.js:796:12)
    at Object.initModels (/Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/build/server.js:821:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/build/server.js:527:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/dc/dev/tix/recobot/stack/backend/build/server.js:497:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

based on 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios

I also tried the convoluted:

```
  mod = await System.import(fn)
  mod.init()
```

same error

```
Error: Cannot find module './models/Projects'.
```

If I hoist the import outside the main code block all runs fine.

```
import Project from "./models/Projects"

const TixBot = {

  async initModels(dbc: any) {
     await Project.init(dbc)
```

btw I am running under webpack which had this issue:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1599

resolved with

```
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
```

in the webpack.config. man, sometimes I'm afraid to look down when working on modern JS...

not very helpful: [Typescript: dynamically import classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852938/typescript-dynamically-import-classes)

related and interesting
https://blog.atomist.com/typescript-imports/

Comment: I guess the other way is to have multiple `index` files and lots of import / export with hardwired paths. sigh

Comment: Are you using SystemJS? It depends on your loader but it's definitely possible. `await require(specifier)` is definitely wrong. `await Promise.all(routeFiles.map(specifier => import(specifier)))` is what you want, but how dynamic it can be and how resolution will work depends on some things

Comment: no I had not heard of `SystemJS` but this is for node/server side and how to use in Typescript is the issue. It doesn't look like that is relevant?
readme: >> "Configurable module loader enabling backwards compatibility workflows for ES modules in browsers. "
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: Well, `System.import` brought SystemJS to mind. If you are on the server side don't worry about that.